# AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'

Tags: python, gcloud, fedora, python-3.9

I've just upgraded from Fedora 32 to Fedora 33 (which comes with Python 3.9). Since then `gcloud` command stopped working:

```
[guy@Gandalf32 ~]$ gcloud 
Error processing line 3 of /home/guy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/XStatic-1.0.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 62, in main
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import encoding
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/re.py", line 124, in <module>
    import enum
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('enum')
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

**Update from GCP support**

[GCP support mentioned](https://issuetracker.google.com/170125513) that the new version `318.0.0` released on `2020.11.10`
should support python 3.9

I updated my gcloud sdk to `318.0.0` and now looks like python 3.9.0 is supported.

To fix this issue run

`gcloud components update`

Fedora 33 includes python 2.7 and to force GCloud SDK to use it please set this environment variable

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2
```

You can add this export command to your `~/.bash_profile`

Python 3.9 is very new and is expected that Gcloud SDK does not support 3.9, it is written to be compatible with 2.7.x & 3.6 - 3.8 (3.8 can cause some compat issues I recommend to use 3.7)

As a workaround, configure Python 3.8 or 3.7 (these versions work well for Gcloud and most of linux distros) as system wide interpreter and try to use gcloud commands.

Comment: Kinda weird that [python38](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=28024) isn't avalibale for `Fedora 32` or `Fedora 33`.  But [python37](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=25903) seems to available for both.

Comment: Python38 is available now on fedora as well.

Comment: Ahhh, the default `python` on `Fedora 32` is a link to `python3` which is currently `python v 3.8`.

Comment: I filed a bug upstream: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172647331

Comment: For Debian or other distros that have multiple python versions: `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.8 gcloud components update`

Comment: You can configure `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` as an absolute path to the python binary as well. I have python installed using homebrew, so on OSX I had to do: `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3 gcloud components update`

Answer (score 102):

For macOS/Homebrew:

```
brew install python@3.8
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.8
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/*/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python3.8

gcloud components update

# the issue is now resolved and you can return to python 3.9
unset CLOUDSDK_PYTHON
```

Comment: I also had to create a symbolic link to python 3.8 in `/usr/local/bin` : 

`/usr/local/bin/python3.8 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/bin/python3.8`

Comment: I had python@3.9 only and so I had to install 3.8 as above and then link it like @Raphaël recommended `brew unlink python@3.9` then `brew link python@3.8`

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't want to stop using python@3.9 everywhere else; I would only want to freeze to 3.8 for gcloud CLI.

Comment: Thanks @RaphaëlLemaire I've now added a line to the solution.

Comment: You could also just do `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2 gcloud components update`

Comment: For some reason my `brew` installations are in `/opt` and I need `sudo` to execute commands at the root level so I had to change the third line to `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/*/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python3.8`

Answer (score 19):

*For Mac OS Users*

First of all you should run `brew update`.

If you have this error:

```sh
Error: homebrew-core is a shallow clone. To `brew update` first run:
  git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow
This restriction has been made on GitHub's request because updating shallow
clones is an extremely expensive operation due to the tree layout and traffic of
Homebrew/homebrew-core. We don't do this for you automatically to avoid
repeatedly performing an expensive unshallow operation in CI systems (which
should instead be fixed to not use shallow clones). Sorry for the inconvenience!
```

Run next commands:

```
git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow
git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask" fetch --unshallow
```

Now,

Update python 3.8 `brew upgrade python@3.8`

Add python 3.8 to PATH `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"`

Use python 3.8 in Cloud SDK `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.8`

Now, you can update gcloud components `gcloud components update`

Comment: This worked, even though i had python 3.9, i had to run the above commands with 3.8

Answer (score 13):

Happened to me after a brew upgrade. Works with python 3.8.

You need to make python3.8 into your shell path. I executed following lines and it worked

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"
alias python=/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on OSX when the answers above didn't.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use Python 2, you can use Python 3.8 on Fedora 33 until the SDK starts supporting Python 3.9.

Install python 3.8 using :

```
sudo dnf install python3.8
```

You can verify your installation by running:

```
python3.8 --version
```

Then set it as the Google Cloud SDK interpreter:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.8
```

After this the SDK should work normally.

Comment: Python 3.8 has some issues with Gcloud SDK, please use 3.7 or 2.7 these versions are more compatible with Gcloud SDK

Answer (score -1):

gcloud will update to version 318 on November 10 and will fix this issue.

Comment: Disabling reporting didn't fix the issue for me:

`gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true`
`CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.9 gcloud config config-helper --format=json`
`AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'`