# Xcode update broke gcloud and gsutil

Tags: python, xcode, macos, gcloud, gsutil

A few hours ago I updated Xcode to the latest version, which caused `gcloud` and `gsutil` commands to stop working. For example, a minute before the update finished, the command `gsutil -m rsync` was working fine.

While writing this question, I noticed I no longer have `git` working.

Since I'm not a Python guy, can someone please explain to me what the hell happened now? I would love some help.

`python -V` output is `Python 2.7.16`.

`python3 -V` output is `Python 3.9.0`.

`pip -V` output is `pip 20.2.3 from /Users/<MY_USER>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

`pip3 -V` output is `pip 20.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)`

This is what I get for `gcloud help`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 62, in main
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import encoding
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 124, in <module>
    import enum
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('enum')
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

And this is what I get for `gsutil help`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 32, in <module>
    import setup  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 57, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import platforms
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 124, in <module>
    import enum
  File "/Users/<MY_USER>/gcloud/sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('enum')
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

Answer (score 15):

So after almost a day with nothing, I found a solution: what I needed to do was set an environment variable named `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` to `/usr/bin/python`.

I edited my `.zprofile` and added:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python"
```

I still have no idea what caused it, so I'll be glad for an explanation if anyone cares to take the time.

Comment: gcloud does not seem to support Python 3.9 yet. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011263/339052 "Python 3.9 is on release candidate and is expected that Gcloud SDK not support 3.9, it is written for be compatible with 2.7.x & 3.6 - 3.8" I had the same problem on Win10 after I updated Python. Seems like gcloud's included Python is not used by default as the newer one was first in the PATH.

Comment: Update 2020-11-04 : Supports Python 3.9 now. I was able to fix the issue using this solution.