# AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util' II

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, python-importlib, pyqtdeploy

I have a problem very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010263/attributeerror-module-importlib-has-no-attribute-util) but I'm not about using gcloud but I'm trying to run `pyqtdeploy`.

I'm facing a strange problem: Running

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.util.spec_from_file_location()
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

..using Python3.8.6 with `importlib-1.0.4` running on a Debian 10 +`testing` machine

while the exact same commands on Fedora 32 also running Python3.8.6 with `importlib-1.0.4` let me use `importlib.util`:

```
>>> importlib.util.spec_from_file_location()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: spec_from_file_location() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Why can the exact same module have an attribute on one system and not on the other?

And how do I make `pyqtdeploy` (and thus `importlib.util`) work as expected?

Background: I'm currently trying to run `pyqtdeploy` inside a Docker container but despite I'm using the same versions of Python and `importlib` it will run on the Fedora host but not inside the container..

Comment: Importing a package doesn't automatically load its submodules.

Comment: sounds legit - but that doesn't answer my question - `pyqtdeploy` will work on one system and not on the other, despite I've installed the same versions of Python and `importlib`. So why do they behave differently?

Comment: @frans Those version numbers don't really tell you anything because `importlib.util` may have already been imported by some other dependency before the `import importlib` line is executed. The fact is, your current code is not robust - you should use e.g. `import importlib.util` instead (i.e. EIBTI applies). To test things properly, put something like the following line before your import `print('\n'.join(key for key in sys.modules if key.startswith('importlib')))`.

Answer (score 0):

user2357112 offers sound advice:

```
from importlib import util
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead e.g. `from importlib import util as iutil` and then `iutil.spec_from_file_location()`.